# Possible for PC to act as router?

Tags: windows-10, router

I have a LAN port in my college dorm but sadly the wifi signals arent that great. Is it possible to connect my phone with Wi-Fi or even wired internet using the laptop?

What I have-
1)Laptop with Lanport (Windows 10 x64 HP 15)
2)The wire which allows to connect Lan port to laptop (RJ45?)
3)An Android phone

Comment: I assume you're trying to connect your Android phone to a wireless network created by your laptop, which has an Internet connection from the LAN port.  Please edit your question with this info : What OS is the laptop running, such as Windows 10 vs Windows 7?  Be as specific as you can, like Windows 7 Service Pack 3.

Comment: also important to know if you college requires authentication and provides IP address when connected to their wall jack.

Comment: @yorik Doesnt require any authentication but i'm not sure how they assign IP.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage yes you are correct, I've added some information

Comment: Yes, it's possible by using the hotspot provided by Windows 10.